# I want to use matplotlib in osx lion

Tags: python, matplotlib, osx-lion

I installed matplotlib from macports, and version of python is 2.7.1.

```
$ sudo port install py27-matplotlib py27-matplotlib-basemap
```

I wrote a sample program below.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from pylab import *
plot([1,2,3])
show()
```

But this didn't work correctly with error log "no module named pylab".

And I tried easy_install.

```
$ sudo easy_install matplotlib
```

In this case, my program worked correctly with no errors.

What is the difference between these two cases(macports and easy_install)?

I think the version of matplotlib is same in two cases.

In case of macports, do I have to redefine include path?

Would you help me??

Comment: Did you read this: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/faq/installing_faq.html#os-x-notes

Answer (score 4):

To ensure a compatible environment, MacPorts Python packages automatically install a MacPorts Python.  By default, you can invoke it via `/opt/local/bin/python2.7`.  And that's where you will find the MacPorts installed `matplotlib` et al. `/usr/bin/python` will invoke the Apple-supplied system Python 2.7.1 and, when you ran `sudo easy_install` you were using the Apple-supplied `easy_install` command associated with the system Python.  That means you now have two Python 2.7 instances installed, each with a separate version of `matplotlib`.  There's nothing wrong with that but you probably want to stick with one or the other.  You can make the MacPorts Python 2.7 be your default by ensuring your SHELL path has `/opt/local/bin` before `/usr/bin` and by using the MacPorts `port select python python27` command.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Ned Deily, the problem is caused because MacPorts installs a separate Python even though OS X ships its own version.

I would suggest you use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) instead of MacPorts to avoid problems like this. Homebrew will use the available package on OS X when possible.

Another suggestion is that it's better to use [`pip`](https://pypi.org/project/pip/) to manage Python package, which is a replacement for `easy_install` and supports uninstalling packages. The benefit of using packaging system (like MacPorts, Debian's `apt`) to manage python package is that they can solve the dependency if the Python package relies on other C libraries. But in case the some Python packages are not included in MacPorts or `apt`, you will need to resolve to `easy_install` or `pip`. And it's usually not a good idea to use two packaging system to manage your python package at the same time.

Comment: The only problem the OP had was using an incorrect shebang line or otherwise invoking the system Python instead of the MacPorts one.  MacPorts provides ports of `pip` to install Python packages that are not already provided as ports.  And using Homebrew is not a magic solution for compatibility problems, witness the many questions on SO.  There are often cases where it's not a good idea to use the Apple-supplied system Python.