# matplotlib on lion installation

Tags: python, matplotlib, osx-lion

I am new to programming. I am trying to install matplotlib module on Mac OS X. I have lion operating system and python 2.7 and I also downloaded mac ports. What do I need to type into my terminal to get mac ports to downloads and install matplotlib on my computer?

Comment: Refer to installation instructions [here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/faq/installing_faq.html#os-x-notes) and you might also find it helpful to peruse the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543148/i-want-to-use-matplotlib-in-osx-lion).

Comment: thank you! the second link was much help

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, all I had to do on Lion was:

```
sudo easy_install matplotlib
```

macports was not required at all.

Comment: I tried to do that earlier and it told me I had the wrong version of gcc. I have since ran a bunch of updates on my mac and I tried it again just now. It worked!!! :)